# how to force URL to open in safari browser not in inbuilt browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

my website is not compatible with facebook/instagram inbuilt browser
i use this code to force url to open in external browser

```
<body onload='sampleFunction()'>
<a class='button' href='intent://example-website.com/#Intent;scheme=https;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end' id='btn-1'>OPEN IN BROWSER</a>
<script>
    function sampleFunction() {
        var url = document.getElementById('btn-1');
        if (url) {
            url.href = 'intent://www.example.in/#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;';
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            var btn = document.getElementById('btn-1');
            if (btn) {
                btn.click();
            }
        }, 1000); // 1 seconds delay (1000 milliseconds)
    }
</script>
```

i don't think it also work in ios please help me to test my code in ios
**note-place below link in your insta bio in ios device and click on it . it will open link in default browser plese reply if it work **

[my website](https://vid-hub0.blogspot.com/2023/11/hiiihfhv.html)

plese help small programmer if it doesent work plese help to find right way
the code and my wesite work proper in android instagram in built browser

Comment: It does not work for me.

Comment: it only work in android put link in insta-bio then check it